# Convert Python String to Latex Formula

Tags: python, latex, sympy

I did try to use Sympy for converting Strings containing math equations to Latex code and Display these Equations as an image.

for Example i did try to use Sympy on:

```
K(Y) = M * X + B
```

This does not work in Sympy. (at least for me)
This will work in Sympy. ( at least for me)

```
M*X + B
```

Maybe someone's got a hint how to change the following to sucessfully embed my Equations inside a GUI:

```
import random
import os
import pikepdf
import fitz  # PyMuPDF, imported as fitz for backward compatibility reasons
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
import sympy as syp
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import _clash1
from functools import partial

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Rectangle
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
from io import BytesIO as StringIO

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    b = ["Lineare Beispielfunktion"]
    a = ["K ( X) =  M * X + B  ", 1, 5]
    Gleichung = a[0]
    Gleichung = latex(sympify(Gleichung))
    
        def render_latex(formula, fontsize=12, dpi=3000, format_='svg'):
            """Renders LaTeX formula into image.
            """
            fig = plt.figure(figsize=(0.01, 0.01))
            fig.text(0, 0, u'${}$'.format(formula), fontsize=fontsize)
            buffer_ = StringIO()
            fig.savefig(buffer_, dpi=dpi, transparent=True, format=format_, bbox_inches='tight', 
            pad_inches=0.0)
            plt.close(fig)
            return buffer_.getvalue()
    
    
    image_bytes = render_latex(Gleichung,fontsize=80, dpi=200, format_='jpg')
        with open('Image_toDisplay', 'wb') as image_file:
            image_file.write(image_bytes)
```

I got the function to generate der Image from Stackoverflow ( can't find source on stackoverflow right now),
But you can find it here (thanks for helping to add source):
[on Github by tonyseek](https://gist.github.com/tonyseek/95c90638cf43a87e723b) 
My Problem is the way iam using Sympy. Obviously I do use it the wrong way.
Any recommendations are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i did try Something which ist not nice but did work for me I will sketch the concept and show code afterwards:

1. split String on '='
   a) using (`import re`) and: `re.split('=', Gleichung)`
2. List Element[0] is part before '=' List Element[1] is part after '='
3. use Sympy to render latex code for each Element
4. join new strings ( latex code strings) by '='
5. give this new string into shown function

   ```
   Gleichung = a[0]
   Gleichung_split = re.split('=', Gleichung)
   Gleichung_back = Gleichung_split [1]
   Gleichung_front = Gleichung_split [0]
   Gleichung_front = latex(sympify(Gleichung_front))
   Gleichung_back = latex(sympify(Gleichung_back))

   Gleichung_split [0]= Gleichung_front
   Gleichung_split [1] = Gleichung_back
   s = "="
   Gleichung_print = s.join(Gleichung_split )
   image_bytes = render_latex(Gleichung_print ,fontsize=80, dpi=200, 
   format_='jpg')
   with open('Image_toDisplay', 'wb') as image_file:
       image_file.write(image_bytes)
   ```

Additional Information: Gleichung is german for Equation. If there is anything i should change or a more pythinic way to do this feel free to contribute.
And one important thing: the render to latex function i got from Stack Overflow if you know the source give me a hint i would like to link this into my question.

Comment: This seems to be the render code - at least one version of it. https://gist.github.com/tonyseek/95c90638cf43a87e723b